# Верстка стиля под IPB

Tags: вёрстка

Что-то я гуглил, гуглил, но ничего не нагуглил. Скажите, как сверстать свой собственный стиль для IPB? И вообще сложно ли это и стоит ли это делать.

Comment: Никто не знает чтоли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Заходишь в админку;
2. Вкладка *"Look and Feel"*;
3. Выбираешь стандартный шаблон;
4. Редактируешь;
5. ...
6. PROFIT!!!!!

Всё же очевидно. Там обычная вёрстка, всё понятно и разбито на группы. Экспорт шаблона производится в XML. Картинки не забываем, которые использовались при создании шаблона. НА счёт картинок слабо помню какая там система. Но сути не меняет.

Comment: Как освобожусь - попробую, потом отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разобрать готовый шаблон и посмотреть что и как.
Не знаю как в IPB, но к примеру под DLE  можно заточить любой шаблон т.к для вывода блоков и форм  там используються теги "{login},{online}". Например мы вставляем в любой участок шаблона  тег {login}, и при открытии странички на этом месте будет форма входа.

Comment: На счет DLE это да. Там спец тегами можно выводить разную информацию.
Но посмотрев готовый шаблон на IPB увидел вот такой вот бред: http://savepic.org/2276787.png
Формат xml.
Теперь кто-нибудь что-нибудь посоветует?

Answer (score 0):

Лол, когда я писал выше, что всё делается из под админки, я имел ввиду действительно ВСЁ.

1. Look and Feel;
2. Напротив нужного шаблона жмём треугольник;
3. Manage Templates and CSS;
   http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1566/20110916074843.png
4. Появляется окно редактора;
   http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/7417/20110916073922.png

Неудобно? **Ctrl+A** -> **Dreamweaver** -> **Ctrl+V**. Не увидел проблемы после своего поста. Видимо не достаточно четко написал, что xml трогать не стоит. Он в **IPB** служит контейнером своеобразным. Вопросов, по идее, возникнуть более не должно :3